# Oracle, how to manually re-instantiate a PL/SQL package?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, plsql, errors, replace

I have a web application which calls a procedure from an Oracle PL/SQL package. Each time the package is replaced in turn of a new release the application runs into an exception `ORA-06508`

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-04068: Der bestehende Status der Packages  wurde  aufgehoben
ORA-04061: Bestehender Status von package body "OPS$XY.PACK_XY" wurde annulliert
ORA-04065: Ausführung nicht erfolgreich, package body "OPS$XY.PACK_XY" wurde geändert oder gelöscht
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: aufgerufene Programmeinheit : "OPS$XY.PACK_XY" konnte nicht gefunden werden
ORA-06512: in Zeile 1
```

From the [Oracle-Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/packages.htm#LNPLS804) I got the info that the package needs to be re-instantiated, which is done by the next PL/SQL call after the `ORA-06508`- error.

Is there a way to re-instantiate this package manually right after `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE` ?

Comment: There is an old  OTN https://community.oracle.com/thread/905490 thread that explains this quite well. Worth looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is NO.

Now you have two options IMHO.

1. You can make the package stateless by removing package variables.
2. You can catch this `ORA-ORA-04061` in the application code and re-execute the command.

Useful links:

[AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f%3Fp%3D100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3516589324948)

[ORA-04061: existing state of  has been invalidated](https://community.oracle.com/thread/905490)